# Illegal assignment from List to Account

Tags: apex, soql, opportunity, account

I'm trying to create a query that returns the `Account`'s Id, Name, BillingState and Phone from an Opportunity however when I do so, I get either:

```
Illegal assignment from List to Account
```

Or

```
Illegal assignment from List to List
```

This is the Apex code that I'm using

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccountFromOppotunity(Id opportunityId) {
        Account acct = [SELECT Accountid, Account.Name, Account.BillingState, Account.Phone FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityId];
        return acct;
    }
}
```

If I use the above code I get the first error message, and if I try to set it to a `List <Account> accts = [...]` I get the 2nd one (changing return type as well)

How can I resolve this? This is my first time using Apex so I'm kinda lost and it looks fine according to [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is on Opportunity, so the result will be an opportunity object, not account.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Account getAccountFromOppotunity(Id opportunityId) {
    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Accountid, Account.Name, Account.BillingState, Account.Phone FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opportunityId];
    return opp.Account;
}
```